# Rectangle rotation around clipping rectangle center

Tags: math, geometry

I have two rectangles where one is a clipping for the other one.
Now I want to rotate the bigger rectangle around the center of the clipping rectangle and adjust x/y values.

[image]

How can I calculate the new x/y values after rotation?

I actually just want to rotate the x/y of the bigger box around the center of the smaller box. So the x/y point of the bigger box is relative to the top/left point of the smaller box. I have the width and height of the smaller box so I can calculate x/y point of the big box relative to the center of small box. The angle to rotate is in degrees. The rotation can be any degree, for example 10.

Comment: What do you mean by " one is a clipping for the other one" ?

Comment: What is the significance of the inner rectangle? Does it ever make a difference from just rotating around the point c? When? How?

Comment: How far have you got yourself? Can you calculate the distance and angle of (x,y) to c? You do know the coordinates of c, don't you?

Comment: What is the angle by which you want to rotate? Looks like roughly 26.31 degrees. Is the angle to rotate by in degrees or in radians?

Comment: I actually just want to rotate the x/y of the bigger box around the center of the smaller box. so the x/y point of the bigger box is relative to the top/left point of the smaller box. I have the Width and height of the smaller box so i can calculate y/x big box relative to the center of small box. The angle to rotate is in degrees. The rotation can be any degree, for example 10.

Comment: Do you know school formulas for rotation around point?

Comment: You are confusing everyone with this boxes. Can you formulate your question more general? It seems you just have a point/vector and want to perform a rotation of this point around an other point (C). This is very straight forward, e.g. you could just use a 2D rotation matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: OP stated in a different question that geometry, math and trigonometry is not a strong point. Who can blame? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rotate a given point `P` around a point `C`, which are defined in the same coordinate system you can use a simple rotation matrix. Calculate the `P` coordinates with respect to `C` (subtraction), then apply rotation with the matrix and go back to original coordinates by adding `C` again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

- determine the angle by which you want to rotate, make sure it suitable for the trigonometric functions (sin(), cos(), ...), i.e. right angle is usually Pi/2
- in case of rotating counterclockwise, it is negative
- determine the coordinates of c, as cx,cy
- process each of the corners of the rectanlge, one by one, for a total of four
- for each corner P, currently at coordinates px,py and to move to px2,py2

  - determine angle between current P and C, using atan2(py-cy, px-cx)
  - to get from degrees to radians (for use with trigonometry) calculate radians=(pi*degrees)/180.0
  - add the desired rotation angle to that current angle, to get newangle
  - determine the distance of current P to C, sqrt((px-cx)*(px-cx) + (py-cy)*(py-cy))
  - multiply the distance (which is not changing by rotation), with the appropriate trigonometric function
  - px2 = distance * cos(newangle)
  - py2 = distance * sin(newangle)

Answer (score 0):

All that matters is the coordinates of the rotation center and the angle.

The most compact formulation is by means of complex numbers (of which I hope you have some understanding; you actually don't need a complex data type, you can expand the formulas).

Let `C` be the center and `α` the angle. Then for any point `P`, the image `Q` is given by

```
Q = (P - C) cis(α) + C
```

where `cis(α) = cos(α) + i sin(α)`.

The inverse rotation is simply given by

```
P = (Q - C) cis(-α) + C.
```